# Maximum Number of Users (Persons / Groups) Per Multi Select User Column

Tags: groups, limitations, person, multi-select

I have a multi select Person / Group (User) column in my SharePoint 2013 list. I would like to know, if there is any limit on the number of users (persons/groups) that can be stored in a multi select user column.

Note: I am not looking for the limit of person columns in a list, which I know is 96, based on TechNet.

Answer (score 1):

there is limit of number of columns in the list which you  mentioned but i don't think their is any limitation on the storing the number of user in that column.

How many user you are thinking to store in it?

couple of hundreds will be but more number means more time to resolve all the ids every time it loads.